# Sphinx: where did the top navigation bar with the classic theme go?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx

Old versions of Sphinx (at least 1.1.3) included a top navigation bar as part of the default theme. Here's an example from the [SymPy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/1.0/index.html) (note that we change the default colors from blue to green):

[image]

I am talking about the bar at the very top.

Newer versions (as of at least 1.3.1, and also the latest version, 1.4.6) of Sphinx do not include this bar:

[image]

Where did it go? How do I get it back? I don't see any reference to it in the [theme options documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that we weren't declaring a theme, so it was just using the default. The default used to be "classic", but they switched to "alabaster" at some point between 1.1.3 and 1.3.1. At the bottom you can see that it thinks it is using alabaster:

[image]

It was still rendering like "classic" because we had copied the classic css file into our `_static` directory to make color changes to it.

The solution is to explicitly add

```
html_theme = 'classic'
```

to the `conf.py`.